# Как десериализовать JSON если имя объекта все время меняется ? - C#

Tags: c#, json

Из "rgDescriptions" нужно получать "cache_expiration" и "market_hash_name"

```
    {
  "success": true,
  "rgInventory": {
    "14686634559": {
      "id": "14686634559",
      "classid": "2942712096",
      "instanceid": "480085569",
      "amount": "1",
      "pos": 1
    },
    "14686634555": {
      "id": "14686634555",
      "classid": "2942712097",
      "instanceid": "480085569",
      "amount": "1",
      "pos": 2
    }
  },
  "rgCurrency": [

  ],
  "rgDescriptions": {
    "2942712096_480085569": {
      "appid": "730",
      "classid": "2942712096",
      "instanceid": "480085569",
      "icon_url": "-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXH5ApeO4YmlhxYQknCRvCo04DEVlxkKgpot7HxfDhjxszJemkV09-5lpKKqPrxN7LEmyVQ7MEpiLuSrYmnjQO3-UdsZGHyd4_Bd1RvNQ7T_FDrw-_ng5Pu75iY1zI97bhLsvQz",
      "icon_url_large": "-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXH5ApeO4YmlhxYQknCRvCo04DEVlxkKgpot7HxfDhjxszJemkV09-5lpKKqPrxN7LEm1Rd6dd2j6eQ9N2t2wK3-ENsZ23wcIKRdQE2NwyD_FK_kLq9gJDu7p_KyyRr7nNw-z-DyIFJbNUz",
      "icon_drag_url": "",
      "name": "AK-47 | \u041a\u0440\u0430\u0441\u043d\u0430\u044f \u043b\u0438\u043d\u0438\u044f",
      "market_hash_name": "AK-47 | Redline (Field-Tested)",
      "market_name": "AK-47 | \u041a\u0440\u0430\u0441\u043d\u0430\u044f \u043b\u0438\u043d\u0438\u044f (\u041f\u043e\u0441\u043b\u0435 \u043f\u043e\u043b\u0435\u0432\u044b\u0445 \u0438\u0441\u043f\u044b\u0442\u0430\u043d\u0438\u0439)",
      "name_color": "D2D2D2",
      "background_color": "",
      "type": "\u0412\u0438\u043d\u0442\u043e\u0432\u043a\u0430, \u0417\u0430\u0441\u0435\u043a\u0440\u0435\u0447\u0435\u043d\u043d\u043e\u0435",
      "tradable": 0,
      "marketable": 1,
      "commodity": 0,
      "market_tradable_restriction": "7",
      "cache_expiration": "2018-08-07T07:00:00Z",
      "descriptions": [
        {
          "type": "html",
          "value": "\u0418\u0437\u043d\u043e\u0441: \u041f\u043e\u0441\u043b\u0435 \u043f\u043e\u043b\u0435\u0432\u044b\u0445 \u0438\u0441\u043f\u044b\u0442\u0430\u043d\u0438\u0439"
        },
        {
          "type": "html",
          "value": " "
        },
        {
          "type": "html",
          "value": "\u041c\u043e\u0449\u043d\u0430\u044f \u0438 \u043d\u0430\u0434\u0435\u0436\u043d\u0430\u044f \u0448\u0442\u0443\u0440\u043c\u043e\u0432\u0430\u044f \u0432\u0438\u043d\u0442\u043e\u0432\u043a\u0430 \u0410\u041a-47 \u2014 \u043e\u0434\u043d\u0430 \u0438\u0437 \u0441\u0430\u043c\u044b\u0445 \u0438\u0437\u0432\u0435\u0441\u0442\u043d\u044b\u0445 \u0432 \u043c\u0438\u0440\u0435. \u041d\u0430\u0438\u0431\u043e\u043b\u0435\u0435 \u0441\u043c\u0435\u0440\u0442\u0435\u043b\u044c\u043d\u0430 \u0441\u0442\u0440\u0435\u043b\u044c\u0431\u0430 \u043a\u043e\u0440\u043e\u0442\u043a\u0438\u043c\u0438 \u0438 \u0442\u043e\u0447\u043d\u044b\u043c\u0438 \u043e\u0447\u0435\u0440\u0435\u0434\u044f\u043c\u0438. \u0420\u0430\u0441\u043a\u0440\u0430\u0448\u0435\u043d\u043e \u0441 \u043f\u043e\u043c\u043e\u0449\u044c\u044e \u0430\u043a\u0432\u0430\u043f\u0435\u0447\u0430\u0442\u0438 \u0441 \u0438\u0441\u043f\u043e\u043b\u044c\u0437\u043e\u0432\u0430\u043d\u0438\u0435\u043c \u0443\u0433\u043b\u0435\u0440\u043e\u0434\u043d\u043e\u0433\u043e \u0432\u043e\u043b\u043e\u043a\u043d\u0430 \u0438 \u0443\u043a\u0440\u0430\u0448\u0435\u043d\u043e \u043d\u0430\u043a\u043b\u0435\u0439\u043a\u0430\u043c\u0438 \u0432 \u0432\u0438\u0434\u0435 \u0442\u043e\u043d\u043a\u0438\u0445 \u043a\u0440\u0430\u0441\u043d\u044b\u0445 \u043b\u0438\u043d\u0438\u0439.\n\n<i>\u041d\u0435 \u0431\u043e\u0439\u0441\u044f \u0432\u044b\u0436\u0438\u043c\u0430\u0442\u044c \u0432\u0441\u0451 \u0434\u043e \u043f\u0440\u0435\u0434\u0435\u043b\u0430<\/i>"
        },
        {
          "type": "html",
          "value": " "
        },
        {
          "type": "html",
          "value": "\u041a\u043e\u043b\u043b\u0435\u043a\u0446\u0438\u044f \u00ab\u0424\u0435\u043d\u0438\u043a\u0441\u00bb",
          "color": "9da1a9",
          "app_data": {
            "def_index": "65535",
            "is_itemset_name": 1
          }
        },
        {
          "type": "html",
          "value": "\r\n",
          "app_data": {
            "def_index": "65535"
          }
        },
        {
          "type": "html",
          "value": " "
        },
        {
          "type": "html",
          "value": "<br><div id=\"sticker_info\" name=\"sticker_info\" title=\"Sticker Details\" style=\"border: 2px solid rgb(102, 102, 102); border-radius: 6px; width=100; margin:4px; padding:8px;\"><center><img width=64 height=48 src=\"https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/apps\/730\/icons\/econ\/stickers\/atlanta2017\/hlr.d3ba669e5d00dba577eed5c92f6b10197aabe2ee.png\"><img width=64 height=48 src=\"https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/apps\/730\/icons\/econ\/stickers\/atlanta2017\/hlr.d3ba669e5d00dba577eed5c92f6b10197aabe2ee.png\"><img width=64 height=48 src=\"https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/apps\/730\/icons\/econ\/stickers\/atlanta2017\/hlr.d3ba669e5d00dba577eed5c92f6b10197aabe2ee.png\"><img width=64 height=48 src=\"https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/apps\/730\/icons\/econ\/stickers\/atlanta2017\/hlr.d3ba669e5d00dba577eed5c92f6b10197aabe2ee.png\"><br>Sticker: HellRaisers | \u0410\u0442\u043b\u0430\u043d\u0442\u0430 2017, HellRaisers | \u0410\u0442\u043b\u0430\u043d\u0442\u0430 2017, HellRaisers | \u0410\u0442\u043b\u0430\u043d\u0442\u0430 2017, HellRaisers | \u0410\u0442\u043b\u0430\u043d\u0442\u0430 2017<\/center><\/div>",
          "app_data": {
            "def_index": "65535"
          }
        }
      ],
      "actions": [
        {
          "name": "\u041e\u0441\u043c\u043e\u0442\u0440\u0435\u0442\u044c \u0432 \u0438\u0433\u0440\u0435\u2026",
          "link": "steam:\/\/rungame\/730\/76561202255233023\/+csgo_econ_action_preview%20S%owner_steamid%A%assetid%D16585677760453559697"
        }
      ],
      "market_actions": [
        {
          "name": "\u041e\u0441\u043c\u043e\u0442\u0440\u0435\u0442\u044c \u0432 \u0438\u0433\u0440\u0435\u2026",
          "link": "steam:\/\/rungame\/730\/76561202255233023\/+csgo_econ_action_preview%20M%listingid%A%assetid%D16585677760453559697"
        }
      ],
      "tags": [
        {
          "internal_name": "CSGO_Type_Rifle",
          "name": "\u0412\u0438\u043d\u0442\u043e\u0432\u043a\u0430",
          "category": "Type",
          "category_name": "\u0422\u0438\u043f"
        },
        {
          "internal_name": "weapon_ak47",
          "name": "AK-47",
          "category": "Weapon",
          "category_name": "\u041e\u0440\u0443\u0436\u0438\u0435"
        },
        {
          "internal_name": "set_community_2",
          "name": "\u041a\u043e\u043b\u043b\u0435\u043a\u0446\u0438\u044f \u00ab\u0424\u0435\u043d\u0438\u043a\u0441\u00bb",
          "category": "ItemSet",
          "category_name": "\u041d\u0430\u0431\u043e\u0440"
        },
        {
          "internal_name": "normal",
          "name": "\u041e\u0431\u044b\u0447\u043d\u044b\u0439",
          "category": "Quality",
          "category_name": "\u041a\u0430\u0442\u0435\u0433\u043e\u0440\u0438\u044f"
        },
        {
          "internal_name": "Rarity_Legendary_Weapon",
          "name": "\u0417\u0430\u0441\u0435\u043a\u0440\u0435\u0447\u0435\u043d\u043d\u043e\u0435",
          "category": "Rarity",
          "color": "d32ce6",
          "category_name": "\u0420\u0435\u0434\u043a\u043e\u0441\u0442\u044c"
        },
        {
          "internal_name": "WearCategory2",
          "name": "\u041f\u043e\u0441\u043b\u0435 \u043f\u043e\u043b\u0435\u0432\u044b\u0445 \u0438\u0441\u043f\u044b\u0442\u0430\u043d\u0438\u0439",
          "category": "Exterior",
          "category_name": "\u041e\u0444\u043e\u0440\u043c\u043b\u0435\u043d\u0438\u0435"
        },
        {
          "internal_name": "Tournament11",
          "name": "ELEAGUE Atlanta 2017",
          "category": "Tournament",
          "category_name": "\u0422\u0443\u0440\u043d\u0438\u0440"
        },
        {
          "internal_name": "Team25",
          "name": "HellRaisers",
          "category": "TournamentTeam",
          "category_name": "\u041a\u043e\u043c\u0430\u043d\u0434\u0430"
        }
      ]
    },
    "2942712097_480085569": {
      "appid": "730",
      "classid": "2942712097",
      "instanceid": "480085569",
      "icon_url": "-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXH5ApeO4YmlhxYQknCRvCo04DEVlxkKgpot7HxfDhjxszJemkV09-5lpKKqPrxN7LEmyVQ7MEpiLuSrYmnjQO3-UdsZGHyd4_Bd1RvNQ7T_FDrw-_ng5Pu75iY1zI97bhLsvQz",
      "icon_url_large": "-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXH5ApeO4YmlhxYQknCRvCo04DEVlxkKgpot7HxfDhjxszJemkV09-5lpKKqPrxN7LEm1Rd6dd2j6eQ9N2t2wK3-ENsZ23wcIKRdQE2NwyD_FK_kLq9gJDu7p_KyyRr7nNw-z-DyIFJbNUz",
      "icon_drag_url": "",
      "name": "AK-47 | \u041a\u0440\u0430\u0441\u043d\u0430\u044f \u043b\u0438\u043d\u0438\u044f",
      "market_hash_name": "AK-47 | Redline (Field-Tested)",
      "market_name": "AK-47 | \u041a\u0440\u0430\u0441\u043d\u0430\u044f \u043b\u0438\u043d\u0438\u044f (\u041f\u043e\u0441\u043b\u0435 \u043f\u043e\u043b\u0435\u0432\u044b\u0445 \u0438\u0441\u043f\u044b\u0442\u0430\u043d\u0438\u0439)",
      "name_color": "D2D2D2",
      "background_color": "",
      "type": "\u0412\u0438\u043d\u0442\u043e\u0432\u043a\u0430, \u0417\u0430\u0441\u0435\u043a\u0440\u0435\u0447\u0435\u043d\u043d\u043e\u0435",
      "tradable": 0,
      "marketable": 1,
      "commodity": 0,
      "market_tradable_restriction": "7",
      "cache_expiration": "2018-08-07T07:00:00Z",
      "descriptions": [
        {
          "type": "html",
          "value": "\u0418\u0437\u043d\u043e\u0441: \u041f\u043e\u0441\u043b\u0435 \u043f\u043e\u043b\u0435\u0432\u044b\u0445 \u0438\u0441\u043f\u044b\u0442\u0430\u043d\u0438\u0439"
        },
        {
          "type": "html",
          "value": " "
        },
        {
          "type": "html",
          "value": "\u041c\u043e\u0449\u043d\u0430\u044f \u0438 \u043d\u0430\u0434\u0435\u0436\u043d\u0430\u044f \u0448\u0442\u0443\u0440\u043c\u043e\u0432\u0430\u044f \u0432\u0438\u043d\u0442\u043e\u0432\u043a\u0430 \u0410\u041a-47 \u2014 \u043e\u0434\u043d\u0430 \u0438\u0437 \u0441\u0430\u043c\u044b\u0445 \u0438\u0437\u0432\u0435\u0441\u0442\u043d\u044b\u0445 \u0432 \u043c\u0438\u0440\u0435. \u041d\u0430\u0438\u0431\u043e\u043b\u0435\u0435 \u0441\u043c\u0435\u0440\u0442\u0435\u043b\u044c\u043d\u0430 \u0441\u0442\u0440\u0435\u043b\u044c\u0431\u0430 \u043a\u043e\u0440\u043e\u0442\u043a\u0438\u043c\u0438 \u0438 \u0442\u043e\u0447\u043d\u044b\u043c\u0438 \u043e\u0447\u0435\u0440\u0435\u0434\u044f\u043c\u0438. \u0420\u0430\u0441\u043a\u0440\u0430\u0448\u0435\u043d\u043e \u0441 \u043f\u043e\u043c\u043e\u0449\u044c\u044e \u0430\u043a\u0432\u0430\u043f\u0435\u0447\u0430\u0442\u0438 \u0441 \u0438\u0441\u043f\u043e\u043b\u044c\u0437\u043e\u0432\u0430\u043d\u0438\u0435\u043c \u0443\u0433\u043b\u0435\u0440\u043e\u0434\u043d\u043e\u0433\u043e \u0432\u043e\u043b\u043e\u043a\u043d\u0430 \u0438 \u0443\u043a\u0440\u0430\u0448\u0435\u043d\u043e \u043d\u0430\u043a\u043b\u0435\u0439\u043a\u0430\u043c\u0438 \u0432 \u0432\u0438\u0434\u0435 \u0442\u043e\u043d\u043a\u0438\u0445 \u043a\u0440\u0430\u0441\u043d\u044b\u0445 \u043b\u0438\u043d\u0438\u0439.\n\n<i>\u041d\u0435 \u0431\u043e\u0439\u0441\u044f \u0432\u044b\u0436\u0438\u043c\u0430\u0442\u044c \u0432\u0441\u0451 \u0434\u043e \u043f\u0440\u0435\u0434\u0435\u043b\u0430<\/i>"
        },
        {
          "type": "html",
          "value": " "
        },
        {
          "type": "html",
          "value": "\u041a\u043e\u043b\u043b\u0435\u043a\u0446\u0438\u044f \u00ab\u0424\u0435\u043d\u0438\u043a\u0441\u00bb",
          "color": "9da1a9",
          "app_data": {
            "def_index": "65535",
            "is_itemset_name": 1
          }
        },
        {
          "type": "html",
          "value": "\r\n",
          "app_data": {
            "def_index": "65535"
          }
        },
        {
          "type": "html",
          "value": " "
        },
        {
          "type": "html",
          "value": "<br><div id=\"sticker_info\" name=\"sticker_info\" title=\"Sticker Details\" style=\"border: 2px solid rgb(102, 102, 102); border-radius: 6px; width=100; margin:4px; padding:8px;\"><center><img width=64 height=48 src=\"https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/apps\/730\/icons\/econ\/stickers\/cluj2015\/sig_furlan_foil.d0409d46f6a46830eb7483e2f2b1b3a2f60af7a3.png\"><img width=64 height=48 src=\"https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/apps\/730\/icons\/econ\/stickers\/cluj2015\/vex_foil.0698beea35ec235e8dd7c7add5610b0de565f10f.png\"><img width=64 height=48 src=\"https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/apps\/730\/icons\/econ\/stickers\/cologne2014\/esl_b.dc0098730f5279deeb3855f1b662b788a4291faf.png\"><img width=64 height=48 src=\"https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/apps\/730\/icons\/econ\/stickers\/eslkatowice2015\/hellraisers_foil.b79f6190cb92b16b6988d2e71090c9cf5b864814.png\"><br>Sticker: Furlan (\u043c\u0435\u0442\u0430\u043b\u043b\u0438\u0447\u0435\u0441\u043a\u0430\u044f) | \u041a\u043b\u0443\u0436-\u041d\u0430\u043f\u043e\u043a\u0430 2015, Vexed Gaming (\u043c\u0435\u0442\u0430\u043b\u043b\u0438\u0447\u0435\u0441\u043a\u0430\u044f) | \u041a\u043b\u0443\u0436-\u041d\u0430\u043f\u043e\u043a\u0430 2015, ESL One Cologne 2014 (\u043a\u0440\u0430\u0441\u043d\u0430\u044f), HellRaisers (\u043c\u0435\u0442\u0430\u043b\u043b\u0438\u0447\u0435\u0441\u043a\u0430\u044f) | \u041a\u0430\u0442\u043e\u0432\u0438\u0446\u0435 2015<\/center><\/div>",
          "app_data": {
            "def_index": "65535"
          }
        }
      ],
      "actions": [
        {
          "name": "\u041e\u0441\u043c\u043e\u0442\u0440\u0435\u0442\u044c \u0432 \u0438\u0433\u0440\u0435\u2026",
          "link": "steam:\/\/rungame\/730\/76561202255233023\/+csgo_econ_action_preview%20S%owner_steamid%A%assetid%D747672600222297361"
        }
      ],
      "market_actions": [
        {
          "name": "\u041e\u0441\u043c\u043e\u0442\u0440\u0435\u0442\u044c \u0432 \u0438\u0433\u0440\u0435\u2026",
          "link": "steam:\/\/rungame\/730\/76561202255233023\/+csgo_econ_action_preview%20M%listingid%A%assetid%D747672600222297361"
        }
      ],
      "tags": [
        {
          "internal_name": "CSGO_Type_Rifle",
          "name": "\u0412\u0438\u043d\u0442\u043e\u0432\u043a\u0430",
          "category": "Type",
          "category_name": "\u0422\u0438\u043f"
        },
        {
          "internal_name": "weapon_ak47",
          "name": "AK-47",
          "category": "Weapon",
          "category_name": "\u041e\u0440\u0443\u0436\u0438\u0435"
        },
        {
          "internal_name": "set_community_2",
          "name": "\u041a\u043e\u043b\u043b\u0435\u043a\u0446\u0438\u044f \u00ab\u0424\u0435\u043d\u0438\u043a\u0441\u00bb",
          "category": "ItemSet",
          "category_name": "\u041d\u0430\u0431\u043e\u0440"
        },
        {
          "internal_name": "normal",
          "name": "\u041e\u0431\u044b\u0447\u043d\u044b\u0439",
          "category": "Quality",
          "category_name": "\u041a\u0430\u0442\u0435\u0433\u043e\u0440\u0438\u044f"
        },
        {
          "internal_name": "Rarity_Legendary_Weapon",
          "name": "\u0417\u0430\u0441\u0435\u043a\u0440\u0435\u0447\u0435\u043d\u043d\u043e\u0435",
          "category": "Rarity",
          "color": "d32ce6",
          "category_name": "\u0420\u0435\u0434\u043a\u043e\u0441\u0442\u044c"
        },
        {
          "internal_name": "WearCategory2",
          "name": "\u041f\u043e\u0441\u043b\u0435 \u043f\u043e\u043b\u0435\u0432\u044b\u0445 \u0438\u0441\u043f\u044b\u0442\u0430\u043d\u0438\u0439",
          "category": "Exterior",
          "category_name": "\u041e\u0444\u043e\u0440\u043c\u043b\u0435\u043d\u0438\u0435"
        },
        {
          "internal_name": "Tournament8",
          "name": "DreamHack Cluj-Napoca 2015",
          "category": "Tournament",
          "category_name": "\u0422\u0443\u0440\u043d\u0438\u0440"
        },
        {
          "internal_name": "Tournament4",
          "name": "ESL One Cologne 2014",
          "category": "Tournament",
          "category_name": "\u0422\u0443\u0440\u043d\u0438\u0440"
        },
        {
          "internal_name": "Tournament6",
          "name": "ESL One Katowice 2015",
          "category": "Tournament",
          "category_name": "\u0422\u0443\u0440\u043d\u0438\u0440"
        },
        {
          "internal_name": "Team47",
          "name": "Vexed Gaming",
          "category": "TournamentTeam",
          "category_name": "\u041a\u043e\u043c\u0430\u043d\u0434\u0430"
        },
        {
          "internal_name": "Team25",
          "name": "HellRaisers",
          "category": "TournamentTeam",
          "category_name": "\u041a\u043e\u043c\u0430\u043d\u0434\u0430"
        },
        {
          "internal_name": "furlan",
          "name": "Furlan (Damian Kislowski)",
          "category": "ProPlayer",
          "category_name": "\u041f\u0440\u043e\u0444\u0435\u0441\u0441\u0438\u043e\u043d\u0430\u043b\u044c\u043d\u044b\u0439 \u0438\u0433\u0440\u043e\u043a"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "more": false,
  "more_start": false
}
```

Comment: Но вам мешает то что ...

Comment: Могли бы и поискать. Вот прям [идентичный](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/435018/Создание-json-класса) JSON, а вот [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/829895/Как-распарсить-json-в-ассоциативный-массив-c) для закрытия вопроса.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как распарсить json в ассоциативный массив / C#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/829895/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-json-%d0%b2-%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%be%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2-c)